# How to navigate from one screen with FlatList to another screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im pretty new to this entire coding stuff and now I've finally arrived to my first unsolvable code-related myth! My problem is that I simply cannot find a way to use FlatList in a way that makes it possible for me to navigate to another screen! (I am using Stack Screen with each item of my 8 item long FlatList being linked to another screen, or at least I try to get there) Here is the code of my screen containing the FlatList:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    FlatList,
    StyleSheet, Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
//export default

class listTest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            helpersList: [
                { ID: 1, title: ' Memories' },
                { ID: 2, title: ' Cute Cats' },
                { ID: 3, title: ' Funny Vids' },
                { ID: 4, title: ' Vegan Recipes' },
                { ID: 5, title: ' Random Jokes' },
                { ID: 6, title: ' Random Knowledge' },
                { ID: 7, title: ' Hydration' },
                { ID: 8, title: ' Memes' },
            ]
        };
    }

    navFunction = (item) => {
        //const navigation = useNavigation();

        if (item.ID === 1) {
            navigation.navigate(' Nice Memories')
            //alert('Whats Up Slappers')
        }
        else if (item.ID === 2) {
            navigation.navigate(' Cute Cats')
            //alert('Whats Up Slappers 2')
        }
        else if (item.ID === 3) {
            navigation.navigate(' Funny Vids')
        }
        else if (item.ID === 4) {
            navigation.navigate(' Vegan Recipes')
        }
        else if (item.ID === 5) {
            navigation.navigate(' Random Jokes')
        }
        else if (item.ID === 6) {
            navigation.navigate(' Random Knowledge')
        }
        else if (item.ID === 7) {
            navigation.navigate(' Hydration')
        }
        else if (item.ID === 8) {
            navigation.navigate(' Memes')
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.helpersList}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                        <Card style={styles.card} onPress={() => this.navFunction(item)}>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.cardText}>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </Card>
                    }
                    keyExtractor={item => item.ID}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#146b3a',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingVertical: 40,
        marginVertical: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
        shadowColor: "black",
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0, },
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        shadowRadius: 5,
    },
    cardText: {
        color: "white",
        fontSize: 20,
    }
})

export default withNavigation(listTest);
```

Right now the main issue I get is, that the variable 'navigation' cannot be found! Ive tried multiple navigation methods but I couldn't get a single one to work. Now I got stuck with 'withNavigation' while exporting but it also doesn't seem to be right!

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Try using `this.props.navigation.navigate()`

Comment: Wow this actually worked!! Thanks a lot! Now I can finally move on! xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useNavigation` is a hook that gives you access to the `navigation` object. This gives you access to the `navigation` object in `Functional Component` also. You can check their [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/).

`withNavigation` is a `Higher Order Component (hoc)` which gives the `navigation` object access through `props`. So if you're wrapping your component with `withNavigation`, you can access it through `props`. [Official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/with-navigation/).

In your `navFunction`, you can use something like this.

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
navigation.navigate(' Nice Memories')
.
.
navigation.navigate(' Cute Cats')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough, yet simple explanation! great!